# Keeping the average user from opening two copies of my program

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, locking

I know that this is an impossible task against someone determined, but I'd like to keep mid-average users from being able to open more than one copy of my program at a time.

Here's the quick code I've made:

```
const tmp = require('tmp'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

// Randomly generated, constant in each copy of the app
const app_code = '19c2cefbfa76b4887a1d4664704a3fe0';

// Write protection here, although it doesn't help much
const lock = tmp.fileSync({ mode: 0444, prefix: app_code});

const filedir = path.dirname(lock.name);
const filename = path.basename(lock.name);

// Search for already running copies
fs.readdirSync(filedir).forEach(f => {
    // If it's made by the app and it's not mine
    if (f.includes(app_code) && f !== filename) {
        // Delete my lock and close
        fs.unlink(lock.name);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});

// Watch for my own lock being deleted
fs.watch(filedir, function(event, who) {
    if (event === 'rename') {
        // If my lock doesn't exist or a new lock has been made
        if (!fs.existsSync(lock.name) || who.includes(app_code)) {
            // Delete my lock and close
            fs.unlink(lock.name);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }
});

// Main program content, use placeholder here:
setInterval(() => console.log("Running alone"), 1000);
```

There are a few issues that I see right off the bat:

- Different tmp folders being used
- Locks being left in place if the program is terminated, meaning no copies could run

Anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: A different type of implementation here: [How to disallow multiple instances of the same app in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944821/how-to-disallow-multple-instances-of-the-same-app-in-node-js/47945476#47945476)

Comment: That seems promising. It looks like it would be more foolproof, but also could have a few shortcomings - I think I'll use it for now at least.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use resource based locking. Consider the following:

- your application uses well known TCP/UDP port. Only single process can bind it.
- your application uses some configuration/database/whatever files in predefined places. `flock` them. Same stands for pid files under `/var/run`.

It is still possible to separate resources with chroot or containers. But if nothing is shared are there any benefits in *forced locking*?

> I'd like to keep mid-average users from being able to open more than one copy of my program at a time.

I guess mid-average users won't use network namespaces, chroots or containers. If they will - I bet they have *the reasones* so let them do the thing.